# Java - Converting an ArrayList< int[] > to int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer

I have an ArrayList< int[] > and would like to convert this to an int[][]. The resulting array has the same int[] for each entry even though they are distinct (yes, I've checked!). Am I missing something simple here? The length of the arrays in int[][] is given by arr.length

```
int[][] vals = new int[ list.size() ][ arr.length ];
list.toArray( vals );
```

**EDIT:**
I've realized that the code works ok, so heres a larger sample of the code where the problem is arising. permute() does as it says and permutes the integers in the given array returning true when a new permutation is done.

```
List< int[] > list = new ArrayList<>();
do {
    list.add( vals );
} while ( permute( vals ) ); // I print vals here and the permutations are all unique each time
int[][] permutations = new int[ list.size() ][];
list.toArray( permutations );
// If I print permutations now, all the arrays inside it are the same
```

Comment: The above code seems to work for me.  A larger example might be needed to help figure out why it isn't working for you.  (FYI, the `arr.length` isn't necessary, and it doesn't really matter what you put in there because the elements of the outer array are references that will get overwritten anyway.  You can just make it `[]`.)

Comment: I've realized that...see the edit with the larger code

Answer (score 2):

```
int[][] vals = new int[ list.size() ][ arr.length ];

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   vals[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Comment: That's not where the problem is.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline FYI, this answer was posted before the OP provided additional information in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the new question: You don't show the declaration of `vals`, but assuming it's declared as `int[]`, `vals` is actually a *reference* to an array.  So every time you do your `list.add`, you're adding the *same* reference to the list.  I assume `permute(vals)` changes the values in the list, but it won't change the reference, which means that at the end of the loop, every item in `list` is the same reference to the same array with the same values.  What you'll need to do is make a copy of the array.  Try this:

```
list.add( Arrays.copyOf (vals, vals.length) );
```

Comment: I'll try that. How come when I print vals then I get the different values each time?

Comment: Are you printing them inside the `do`..`while` loop?  Yes, the values inside `vals` do change.  But since `vals` is a _reference_ and you were adding the same reference as each list item, every time the values inside `vals` changed, that means that every list item, which pointed to the same array, would also have values that changed, because `list` is storing a reference to `vals` and not the actual values inside `vals`.

Comment: `list.add(vals.clone());` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs carefully http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29

You need

```
vals = list.toArray(vals);
```

I don't know why it does not work for some of you - it works for me very well

Comment: That returns an `Object[]`.

Comment: Actually, if you do it this way, the returned array will be an `Object[]` not an `int[][]`.

Comment: @arshajii
@StephenC
`list.toArray(vals);` returns correct type

Comment: OK, the edit now results in code that actually compiles, which is an improvement, but it's still no different from the original post.  `list.toArray(vals)` will put the values in `vals` as long as `vals` is large enough to hold them.  It creates a new array only if the argument is too short.  And in the OP's code, it wasn't too short.  So assigning `vals` to the result,  in this case, makes no difference.

Comment: OK, my bad. I prefer to USE parameter(s) and return result(s). I did not read the docs completely myself.